# title in in list of indexed search contains only the title of the main page and not the seo title

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

TYPO3 9.7 LTS, indexed search. I get in my hit list the correct links to all my pages but the titles contains only the title of the detail page and not the html-title of the resulting page. So i end up with dozens of search titles like "detail" for all news and every other extension.

in older versions of TYPO3 this works ...

Can anybody give me a hint? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact version? If its not up to date, maybe this https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88041 or maybe old index entries

Comment: Thanks for your hint! See my answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some researching and with the hint of Jonas Osburg (thanks!) i found the problem. indexed_search was refactored to use the the TYPO3 pagetitle-API. These lines:

```
        if ($this->conf['indexedDocTitle']) {
            $this->contentParts['title'] = $this->conf['indexedDocTitle'];
        }
```

in indexer.php of indexed_search are responsible for the changed behavior. A real dirty hack would be to comment these lines ... well, dont do this!

The real solution seems to be the implementation of a PageTitleProvider in every extension which shows multiple data on a single page. An detailed description and example could be found here:

https://www.richardhaeser.com/typo3-blog/using-pagetitle-api-of-typo3